# Can not find child element of UL

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure what I'm missing. Here's my HTML:

```
    <ul class="top-level">
        <li class="agency"><a href="contentAgency.php?id=6" class="test">Client</a>
        <ul class="agency-sub">
            <li><a href="">Targeting this</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><Multiple entries</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Here is my function:

```
$("ul.top-level").on("click", "ul.top-level li.agency a.test", function (event) {
    var numbs = $(this).attr("href").match(/id=([0-9]+)/)[1];
    $("#content-display article").hide();
    $(this).children().find("a").addClass("sub-active");
    $(this).parent().siblings().find("ul").hide();
    showContentAgency(numbs, this);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I am trying to add the class `sub-active` to the nested `ul li a` tag when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$(this).children()` use `$(this).next()` because `ul` element which you are looking for is a sibling of `a.test` element which is being clicked.

Try this.

```
$("ul.top-level").on("click", "li.agency a.test", function (event) {
    var numbs = $(this).attr("href").match(/id=([0-9]+)/)[1];
    $("#content-display article").hide();
    $(this).next().find("a").addClass("sub-active");
    $(this).parent().siblings().find("ul").hide();
    showContentAgency(numbs, this);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, something is still off. I created a fiddle and added the `showContentAgency(numbs, this);`function as well: http://jsfiddle.net/pKLpa/

Comment: Your selector(second argument for `on()`) was wrong http://jsfiddle.net/pKLpa/1/. I have edited my answer as well.

Comment: OK, now it applies `sub-active`to all of the nested hrefs in my list. How can I target just the closet one?

Comment: What do you mean by closest? The first link?

Comment: I updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pKLpa/3/. When I click on say, `Client 2` I'd like `sub-active`to be applied to that href. And then `nav-active`should remain applied to `this`.

Comment: *Exactly* like that. Thank you!

Comment: I think it deserves +1 too :)

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the `a.test` element..

So you probably need to change

```
$(this).children().find("a").addClass("sub-active");
```

to

```
$(this).addClass("sub-active");
```

---

Quoting the [documentation of `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

> When a *selector* is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated. **The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector**. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.

Comment: But I'm trying to select the href in the nested ul of `this`

Answer (score 0):

`$("ul.top-level").on("click", "ul.top-level li.agency a.test"` will select the link containing the text "Client", which becomes `$(this)`.

`$(this).children()` has no context because the link has no children. You probably want:  `$(this).parent().next().children()`

`$(this).parent().siblings().find("ul").hide();` will select siblings of "agency", there are none, for the find('ul').children will not work either.

Comment: Hi, I added the `showContentAgency(numbs, this);` to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pKLpa/, something is still off.